# Querying a database in joomla article

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am unable to query the database inside an article in joomla 2.5. I tried copying some codes from sites and creating an article with the codes as the content but its just showing the raw code. I have searched google but there is no comprehensive tutorial on this, starting from the beginning. So my question is how can i use JFactory or how and where can i query a database with joomla in an article ?. I just want to query the database and use joomla to display the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add code to a Joomla article by default. You need to use a plugin. For this I would highly recommend [Sourcerer](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer).

Once installed, you can add code to your articles like so:

```
{source}
<?php
    $user = JFactory::getUser;
    echo 'Hello' . $user->username;
?>
{/source}
```

There will be a button below the article content area which will bring up a popup window allowing you to add your code.

Hope this helps